# AWS Elastic BeanStalk .ebextensions Package Manager for Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

The [AWS Elastic BeanStalk Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) specifically wrote:

> Elastic Beanstalk currently supports the following package managers: yum, rubygems, python, and rpm.

So, what should I do if I want to install some packages on an Ubuntu image?

Can I replace `yum`/`rpm` lines with `apt`?

([Someone once blogged this example](http://www.delarre.net/posts/deploying-libcouchbase-with-aws-elasticbeanstalk/):)

```
packages:
  yum:
    libmemcached: []
    ruby-devel: []
    gcc: []
  rpm:
    epel: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
  rubygems:
    chef: '0.10.2'
  apt:
    mysql-client: []
```

(I cannot find explanation about the `apt:` section in the AWS Documentations, though.)

Answer (score 0):

apt-get is a package manager for Ubuntu/Debian based distros, it will not be found in Amazon Linux or RedHat.

You want to use yum.